# Laravel|Octobercms Function to convert time

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

I currently have a belongs to many relation where a user has a list of items they have watched:

```
'shows_watchlist' => [
    'Teranode\Anime\Models\Anime',
    'table' => 'anime_watchlist',
    'key' => 'user_id',
    'otherKey' => 'show_id',
    'order' => 'title asc',
    'pivot' => ['status', 'rating', 'episodes']
],
```

each show has an average duration set for them (so you would access it be $show->duration if trying to get a single show). Im using octobercms for this so the setup is a bit different to laravel.

the duration is formatted as: HH:MM:SS

the relation also specifies how many episodes you have completed for each show via pivot relation. What I need to do is get a calculation of all the relations shows (user's watchlist) and total it with the addition of calculating it towards how many episodes they have watched per show. and then to display that in twig.